# join on 3 tables including sys.tables for table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

We have a master table as follows:

tbl_PMSMaster:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
 background-color: #104E8B; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>SrNo</th><th>CLSID</th><th>Table_Name</th><th>EvaluatorName</th></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>1234567891</td><td>tbl_InboundMonitoring</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>9820247015</td><td>tbl_FOCaseEval</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>4567890</td><td>tbl_InboundMonitoring</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>1111111</td><td>tbl_RetentionEvaluation</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
</table>
```

And Different tables like tbl_InboundMonitoring, tbl_FOCaseEval, tbl_RetentionEvaluation etc. All these tables have columns CLSID and EvaluatorName,  which are filled at the time of data entry.

Need to update the Column EvaluatorName in tbl_PMSMaster which has only CLSID column filled.

How to update using join or something with these two tables and sys.tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_PMSMaster p SET p.EvaluatorName = i.EvaluatorName
INNER JOIN tbl_InboundMonitoring i ON i.CLSID = p.CLSID
```

I have only used `tbl_InboundMonitoring` in this case, but you can replace that with any other table you mentioned or join other tables in the same manner.

**UPDATE**

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableToUpdate VARCHAR
DECLARE @TableFrom VARCHAR

SET @TableToUpdate = 'tbl_PMSMaster'
SET @TableFrom = 'tbl_InboundMonitoring'

SET @Query = 'UPDATE ' +  @TableToUpdate + ' p SET p.EvaluatorName = i.EvaluatorName
INNER JOIN '+ @TableFrom +' i ON i.CLSID = p.CLSID'

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: That is right just for one table, but as there are number of tables beed a generic query where table name can be dynamically replaced with different table names